# stack.screen not working. contents inside stack.screen is not showing on the expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

`ScreenHeaderBtn` in the `<Stack.Screen>` is not showing in expo. Only the contents under the `View` is showing in expo. I have imported stack. Is there something that needs to be installed or imported to use `<Stack.Screen>`?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View , ScrollView, Text, SafeAreaView, Button }  from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import { COLORS, FONT, SIZES, images, icons } from '../constants';
import { Nearbyjobs, Popularjobs, Welcome, ScreenHeaderBtn } from '../components'
import { setStatusBarBackgroundColor } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { isConfigured } from 'react-native-reanimated/lib/reanimated2/core';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Home = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor:COLORS.red },
          headerShadowVisible: false,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.menu} dimension="60%" />
          ), 
          headerRight: () => (
            <ScreenHeaderBtn iconUrl={icons.profile} dimension="100%" />    
          ), 
          headerTitle: ""
        }} 
      /> 
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium }}>
          <Welcome />
          <Popularjobs />
          <Nearbyjobs />
        </View>
      </ScrollView> 
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: I see that you're also following the YT tutorial on React Native. Were you able to fix the hidden header issue ? The answer below didn't help :(

Answer (score 2):

```
import { IconButton } from "react-native-paper";

      <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            headerShadowVisible: false,
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "red" },
            headerLeft: (props) => (
              <IconButton {...props} icon="home" />
            ),
            headerRight: (props) => (
              <IconButton {...props} icon="logout" onPress={LogoutAlert} />
            ),
            headerTitle: "Home",
          }}
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
```

[view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Sm6.png)

there might be issue in your custom ScreenHeaderBtn component, that you are using instead try the above code I provided

else provide your ScreenHeaderBtn component code so I can debug the issue in that

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the _layout.js file

Comment: Please [edit] to make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/77632882/7733418 Is there a relevant difference between adding and saving the mentioned file? Why is saving better than adding? Or is it about the relative path? What is its effect? Why is that relevant?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35559479)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an app/_layout.js file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35382531)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on the topic, but I was struggling with the same error.

What solved the issue for me was renaming the `layout.js` file to `_layout.js`.

For some reason the file was not rendered without the underscore as prefix.